# Resource.String does not contain a definition for 'Hello'

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, publish

I'm trying to publish a Xamarin.Forms project with Visual Studio 2015
by following the steps on [this address](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/#Create_a_New_Keystore).

What I have done so far :
I have changed the to project's build configuration as Release mode
and have created the keystore then published the project
by using Tools/Android/Publish Android App.

But I get these errors when I run the project in Release mode:

> Resource.String does not contain a definition for 'Application.Name'
>   
>   Resource.String does not contain a definition for 'Hello'

Any ideas ?

Note: This option is not seen on my Visual Studio:
[image]

My Android Manifest file :
[image]

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of Android Manifest file?

Comment: Could you explain that file? Sorry I'm new to Xamarin

Comment: Within Solution Explorer,  Right click Android project,  Click Options. Manifest file opens. Otherwise you can open it directly also.  Within Android project open the Properties folder (drop down).  Double click Manifest file.  After opening manifest,  share a screenshot

Comment: What is application name in that?

Comment: Excuse me I wanted to hide because the project is not yet published on Google Play, yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of error can occur due to changing resource files. This can be resolved by Cleaning the solution and Re- Building it again

Answer (score 3):

Can you check if  Xamarin.Droid project contains Strings.xml file in Resources > Values with following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="Hello">Hello World, Click Me!</string>
   <string name="ApplicationName">$projectname$</string>
</resources>
```

Also make sure Build Action is AndroidResource in Properties of Strings.xml.

Comment: Yes there is a file like that with the same content at project.Droid\obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Forms.Platform\library_project_imports\res\values. But I couldn't understand the rest. AndroidResource?

Comment: Very helpful! In my project, Strings.xml existed but was not included in the project.